# Problems in Moving a file 

Tags: php

i am trying to move a file with the following code:

```
$f = 'image.jpeg';
$source ='/Waiting/$f';
$destination = '/Excepted/$f';
copy($source, $destination) or die("Error 1");
```

However I get this error every time:

```
Warning: copy(Waiting/$f) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\gallery\v2\excepted.php on line 13
```

I realize it is because there is no file but it is not picking up the variables.

Answer (score 2):

because you are using ' instead of "

your code should be

```
$f = "image.jpeg";
$source ="/Waiting/$f";
$destination = "/Excepted/$f";
copy($source, $destination) or die("Error 1");
```

' is not working for $variable.

example:

```
<?php
$f="file";
echo 'myfile: $f';
echo "<br/>";
echo "myfile: $f";
?>
```

you will see following result

```
myfile: $f
myfile: file
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double quotes if you want variable parsing to work

```
$source = "/Waiting/$f";
```

Comment: also known as string interpolation

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be:

```
$f = 'image.jpeg';
$source ='/Waiting/'.$f;
$destination = '/Excepted/'.$f;
copy($source, $destination) or die("Error 1");
```

This means that you combine string `Waiting` and variable $f... This should work...

Hope it helps!

---

Try using this (since PHP 5.0 Linux or PHP 5.3.1 on Windows):

```
$f = 'image.jpeg';
$source ='/Waiting/'.$f;
$destination = '/Excepted/'.$f;
rename($source, $destination);
```

This function should to the job better... It will do all at once (make file on new destination and delete old one)...

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$f = 'image.jpeg';
$source = "/Waiting/$f"; // both values are in double quotes
$destination = "/Excepted/$f"; // both values are in double quotes
copy($source, $destination) or die("Error 1");
```

hope it works